# WiX Burn 3.7 and Postgresql Registry Search fail

Tags: postgresql, wix, burn

I'm trying to build a bundle which with postgresql as prerequisite.
I'm trying to detect postgresql by searching into registry as follows:

```
<Fragment>
<util:RegistrySearch Id ="PostgresqlPath_x64"
   Root="HKLM"
   Key="SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.1"
   Result="exists"
   Variable="PostgresqlInstalled_x64"
   Win64="yes" />

<util:RegistrySearch Id="Postgresql_x86"
  Root="HKLM"
  Key="SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-9.1"
  Result="exists"
  Variable="PostgresqlInstalled_x86" 
  Win64="no"/>
```

and then use it in ExePackage:

```
<ExePackage SourceFile="..\..\bin\external_software\postgreSQL\postgresql-9.1.6-1-windows-x64.exe"
              InstallCommand="$(var.PostgresqlInstallCommand)"
              InstallCondition="VersionNT64"
              DetectCondition="PostgresqlInstalled_x64" 
              PerMachine="yes" 
              Compressed="yes"/>

  <ExePackage SourceFile="..\..\bin\external_software\postgreSQL\postgresql-9.1.6-1-windows.exe"
              InstallCommand="$(var.PostgresqlInstallCommand)"
              InstallCondition="(NOT VersionNT64)"
              DetectCondition="PostgresqlInstalled_x86"
              PerMachine="yes" Compressed="yes" />
```

It evaluates to false even when the Postgresql is installed, no matter on what Win Version (x86 or x64) I'm testing.
Am I doing anything wrong here or? :/

Here the compete log file of install:

```
    [072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:32:15]i001: Burn v3.7.1224.0, Windows v6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1), path: C:\Users\A521064\Desktop\sLIM_Bootstrapper.exe, cmdline: ''
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:32:15]i000: Initializing string variable 'PostgresqlUninstall' to value 'PostgreSQL\9.1\uninstall-postgresql.exe'
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:32:15]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\A521064\AppData\Local\Temp\sLIM_Controller_(Bundle)_20131008153215.log'
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:32:15]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\A521064\Desktop\sLIM_Bootstrapper.exe'
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:32:15]i052: Condition 'VersionNT >= v5.1' evaluates to true.
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:32:15]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'sLIM Controller (Bundle)'
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:32:16]i100: Detect begin, 3 packages
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:32:16]i052: Condition 'PostgresqlInstalled_x64' evaluates to false.
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:32:16]i052: Condition 'PostgresqlInstalled_x86 OR PostgresqlInstalled_x86_2' evaluates to false.
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:32:16]i101: Detected package: postgresql_9.1.6_1_windows_x64.exe, state: Absent, cached: None
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:32:16]i101: Detected package: postgresql_9.1.6_1_windows.exe, state: Absent, cached: None
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:32:16]i101: Detected package: sLIMInstall.msi, state: Absent, cached: None
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:32:16]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:32:17]i200: Plan begin, 3 packages, action: Install
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:32:17]i052: Condition 'VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:32:17]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: postgresql_9.1.6_1_windows_x64.exe
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:32:17]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_postgresql_9.1.6_1_windows_x64.exe' to value 'C:\Users\A521064\AppData\Local\Temp\sLIM_Controller_(Bundle)_20131008153215_0_postgresql_9.1.6_1_windows_x64.exe.log'
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:32:17]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_postgresql_9.1.6_1_windows_x64.exe' to value 'C:\Users\A521064\AppData\Local\Temp\sLIM_Controller_(Bundle)_20131008153215_0_postgresql_9.1.6_1_windows_x64.exe_rollback.log'
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:32:17]i052: Condition '(NOT VersionNT64)' evaluates to false.
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:32:17]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: postgresql_9.1.6_1_windows.exe
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:32:17]i052: Condition 'VersionNT64 >= v5.1' evaluates to true.
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:32:17]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_sLIMInstall.msi' to value 'C:\Users\A521064\AppData\Local\Temp\sLIM_Controller_(Bundle)_20131008153215_1_sLIMInstall.msi_rollback.log'
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:32:17]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_sLIMInstall.msi' to value 'C:\Users\A521064\AppData\Local\Temp\sLIM_Controller_(Bundle)_20131008153215_1_sLIMInstall.msi.log'
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:32:17]i201: Planned package: postgresql_9.1.6_1_windows_x64.exe, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: None
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:32:17]i201: Planned package: postgresql_9.1.6_1_windows.exe, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:32:17]i201: Planned package: sLIMInstall.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:32:17]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:32:17]i300: Apply begin
[0B08:0AB8][2013-10-08T15:32:20]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[0B08:0AB8][2013-10-08T15:32:33]i361: Created a system restore point.
[0B08:0AB8][2013-10-08T15:32:33]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\A521064\AppData\Local\Temp\{cef60084-9565-4990-b3d6-2704a4475eab}\.be\sLIM_Bootstrapper.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{cef60084-9565-4990-b3d6-2704a4475eab}\sLIM_Bootstrapper.exe'
[0B08:0AB8][2013-10-08T15:32:33]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {cef60084-9565-4990-b3d6-2704a4475eab}, version: 0.9.18.0
[0B08:0960][2013-10-08T15:32:39]i305: Verified acquired payload: postgresql_9.1.6_1_windows_x64.exe at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\postgresql_9.1.6_1_windows_x64.exe, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\E8DC6F6A96D4A4821F149FA9CA67B35C506645C1\postgresql-9.1.6-1-windows-x64.exe.
[0B08:0960][2013-10-08T15:32:39]i305: Verified acquired payload: sLIMInstall.msi at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\sLIMInstall.msi, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{4E9DAE71-AC58-4A0C-A63F-2AC752C983EF}v0.9.19\sLIMInstall.msi.
[0B08:0AB8][2013-10-08T15:32:40]i301: Applying execute package: postgresql_9.1.6_1_windows_x64.exe, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\E8DC6F6A96D4A4821F149FA9CA67B35C506645C1\postgresql-9.1.6-1-windows-x64.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\E8DC6F6A96D4A4821F149FA9CA67B35C506645C1\postgresql-9.1.6-1-windows-x64.exe" --mode unattended --superpassword postgres --servicepassword postgres --debuglevel 4 --unattendedmodeui none --install_runtimes 0'
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:34:01]i319: Applied execute package: postgresql_9.1.6_1_windows_x64.exe, result: 0x0, restart: None
[0B08:0AB8][2013-10-08T15:34:01]i323: Registering package dependency provider: {4E9DAE71-AC58-4A0C-A63F-2AC752C983EF}, version: 0.9.19, package: sLIMInstall.msi
[0B08:0AB8][2013-10-08T15:34:01]i301: Applying execute package: sLIMInstall.msi, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{4E9DAE71-AC58-4A0C-A63F-2AC752C983EF}v0.9.19\sLIMInstall.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7"'
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:34:42]i319: Applied execute package: sLIMInstall.msi, result: 0x0, restart: None
[0B08:0AB8][2013-10-08T15:34:42]i325: Registering dependency: {cef60084-9565-4990-b3d6-2704a4475eab} on package provider: {4E9DAE71-AC58-4A0C-A63F-2AC752C983EF}, package: sLIMInstall.msi
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:34:42]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x0, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:34:45]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x0
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:34:45]i410: Variable: PostgresqlUninstall = PostgreSQL\9.1\uninstall-postgresql.exe
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:34:45]i410: Variable: VersionNT = 6.1.0.0
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:34:45]i410: Variable: VersionNT64 = 6.1.0.0
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:34:45]i410: Variable: WixBundleAction = 4
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:34:45]i410: Variable: WixBundleElevated = 1
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:34:45]i410: Variable: WixBundleInstalled = 0
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:34:45]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog = C:\Users\A521064\AppData\Local\Temp\sLIM_Controller_(Bundle)_20131008153215.log
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:34:45]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_postgresql_9.1.6_1_windows_x64.exe = C:\Users\A521064\AppData\Local\Temp\sLIM_Controller_(Bundle)_20131008153215_0_postgresql_9.1.6_1_windows_x64.exe.log
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:34:45]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_sLIMInstall.msi = C:\Users\A521064\AppData\Local\Temp\sLIM_Controller_(Bundle)_20131008153215_1_sLIMInstall.msi.log
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:34:45]i410: Variable: WixBundleManufacturer = Atos IT Solutions and Services
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:34:45]i410: Variable: WixBundleName = sLIM Controller (Bundle)
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:34:45]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSource = C:\Users\A521064\Desktop\sLIM_Bootstrapper.exe
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:34:45]i410: Variable: WixBundleProviderKey = {cef60084-9565-4990-b3d6-2704a4475eab}
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:34:45]i410: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_postgresql_9.1.6_1_windows_x64.exe = C:\Users\A521064\AppData\Local\Temp\sLIM_Controller_(Bundle)_20131008153215_0_postgresql_9.1.6_1_windows_x64.exe_rollback.log
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:34:45]i410: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_sLIMInstall.msi = C:\Users\A521064\AppData\Local\Temp\sLIM_Controller_(Bundle)_20131008153215_1_sLIMInstall.msi_rollback.log
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:34:45]i410: Variable: WixBundleTag = 
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:34:45]i410: Variable: WixBundleVersion = 0.9.18.0
[072C:0664][2013-10-08T15:34:45]i007: Exit code: 0x0, restarting: No
```

And on Uninstall again it doesn't find the reg key:

```
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:47:54]i001: Burn v3.7.1224.0, Windows v6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1), path: C:\Users\A521064\Desktop\sLIM_Bootstrapper.exe, cmdline: ''
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:47:54]i000: Initializing string variable 'PostgresqlUninstall' to value 'PostgreSQL\9.1\uninstall-postgresql.exe'
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:47:54]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\A521064\AppData\Local\Temp\sLIM_Controller_(Bundle)_20131008154754.log'
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:47:54]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\A521064\Desktop\sLIM_Bootstrapper.exe'
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:47:54]i052: Condition 'VersionNT >= v5.1' evaluates to true.
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:47:54]i100: Detect begin, 3 packages
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:47:54]i052: Condition 'PostgresqlInstalled_x64' evaluates to false.
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:47:54]i052: Condition 'PostgresqlInstalled_x86 OR PostgresqlInstalled_x86_2' evaluates to false.
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:47:54]i101: Detected package: postgresql_9.1.6_1_windows_x64.exe, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:47:54]i101: Detected package: postgresql_9.1.6_1_windows.exe, state: Absent, cached: None
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:47:54]i101: Detected package: sLIMInstall.msi, state: Present, cached: Complete
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:47:54]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:48:07]i200: Plan begin, 3 packages, action: Uninstall
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:48:07]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_sLIMInstall.msi' to value 'C:\Users\A521064\AppData\Local\Temp\sLIM_Controller_(Bundle)_20131008154754_0_sLIMInstall.msi_rollback.log'
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:48:07]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_sLIMInstall.msi' to value 'C:\Users\A521064\AppData\Local\Temp\sLIM_Controller_(Bundle)_20131008154754_0_sLIMInstall.msi.log'
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:48:07]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: postgresql_9.1.6_1_windows.exe
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:48:07]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: postgresql_9.1.6_1_windows_x64.exe
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:48:07]i201: Planned package: sLIMInstall.msi, state: Present, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: Uninstall, rollback: Install, cache: No, uncache: Yes, dependency: Unregister
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:48:07]i201: Planned package: postgresql_9.1.6_1_windows.exe, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:48:07]i201: Planned package: postgresql_9.1.6_1_windows_x64.exe, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: Yes, dependency: None
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:48:07]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:48:07]i300: Apply begin
[0600:0B3C][2013-10-08T15:48:09]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[0600:0B3C][2013-10-08T15:48:19]i361: Created a system restore point.
[0600:0B3C][2013-10-08T15:48:19]i326: Removed dependency: {cef60084-9565-4990-b3d6-2704a4475eab} on package provider: {4E9DAE71-AC58-4A0C-A63F-2AC752C983EF}, package sLIMInstall.msi
[0600:0B3C][2013-10-08T15:48:19]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {4E9DAE71-AC58-4A0C-A63F-2AC752C983EF}, package: sLIMInstall.msi
[0600:0B3C][2013-10-08T15:48:19]i301: Applying execute package: sLIMInstall.msi, action: Uninstall, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{4E9DAE71-AC58-4A0C-A63F-2AC752C983EF}v0.9.19\sLIMInstall.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7"'
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:48:22]i319: Applied execute package: sLIMInstall.msi, result: 0x0, restart: None
[0600:0B3C][2013-10-08T15:48:22]i351: Removing cached package: sLIMInstall.msi, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{4E9DAE71-AC58-4A0C-A63F-2AC752C983EF}v0.9.19\
[0600:0B3C][2013-10-08T15:48:22]i351: Removing cached package: postgresql_9.1.6_1_windows_x64.exe, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\E8DC6F6A96D4A4821F149FA9CA67B35C506645C1\
[0600:0B3C][2013-10-08T15:48:22]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {cef60084-9565-4990-b3d6-2704a4475eab}
[0600:0B3C][2013-10-08T15:48:22]i352: Removing cached bundle: {cef60084-9565-4990-b3d6-2704a4475eab}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{cef60084-9565-4990-b3d6-2704a4475eab}\
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:48:23]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x0, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:48:43]i500: Shutting down, exit code: 0x0
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:48:43]i410: Variable: PostgresqlUninstall = PostgreSQL\9.1\uninstall-postgresql.exe
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:48:43]i410: Variable: VersionNT = 6.1.0.0
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:48:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleAction = 3
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:48:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleElevated = 1
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:48:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleInstalled = 1
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:48:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog = C:\Users\A521064\AppData\Local\Temp\sLIM_Controller_(Bundle)_20131008154754.log
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:48:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleLog_sLIMInstall.msi = C:\Users\A521064\AppData\Local\Temp\sLIM_Controller_(Bundle)_20131008154754_0_sLIMInstall.msi.log
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:48:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleManufacturer = Atos IT Solutions and Services
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:48:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleName = sLIM Controller (Bundle)
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:48:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSource = C:\Users\A521064\Desktop\sLIM_Bootstrapper.exe
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:48:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleProviderKey = {cef60084-9565-4990-b3d6-2704a4475eab}
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:48:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_sLIMInstall.msi = C:\Users\A521064\AppData\Local\Temp\sLIM_Controller_(Bundle)_20131008154754_0_sLIMInstall.msi_rollback.log
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:48:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleTag = 
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:48:43]i410: Variable: WixBundleVersion = 0.9.18.0
[0AC0:05E0][2013-10-08T15:48:43]i007: Exit code: 0x0, restarting: No
```

RegSearch from my MSI works:

```
<Property Id="POSTGRESQLX64">
      <RegistrySearch Id='PostgresqlX64RegSearch'
                Root='HKLM'
                Key='SOFTWARE\PostgreSQL\Installations\postgresql-x64-9.1'
                Name="Version" 
                Win64="yes"       
                Type ="raw" />
    </Property>
```

And the log:

```
AppSearch: Property: POSTGRESQLX64, Signature: PostgresqlX64RegSearch
MSI (c) (08:4C) [15:34:04:011]: Note: 1: 2262 2: Signature 3: -2147287038 
MSI (c) (08:4C) [15:34:04:011]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding POSTGRESQLX64 property. Its value is '9.1.6.1'.
AppSearch: Property: POSTGRESQL_SERVICE, Signature: PostgresqlServiceRegSearch
```

Comment: Can you post the complete log file?

Comment: @StephenJennings please have a look at my last edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Burn is not calling either of your RegistrySearch elements because you've defined them in a `<Fragment>` but haven't referenced them in your `<Bundle>`.

You can do one of the following:

- Add `<util:RegistrySearchRef>` elements inside your `<Bundle>`
- Nest the `<util:RegistrySearch>` elements under `<Bundle>`

According to Rob Mensching in a mailing list post, [referencing an item in a fragment with a `<FoobarRef>` element brings in the whole fragment](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/How-to-reference-elements-in-a-Fragment-which-do-not-have-a-XxxxRef-construct-tp7590454p7590458.html):

> When one thing is referenced in a Fragment the whole Fragment is pulled in.... The other elements you list are typically support elements so they can go in with some item that can be referenced. For example, the XxxSequence elements can go in a Fragment with the CustomAction being scheduled. Then you use a CustomActionRef to say, "Hey, I want that CustomAction and I don't want to think about how it gets scheduled."

When the `<RegistrySearch>` elements are being referenced, you'll see log entries like this:

```
[2218:2F1C][2013-10-09T10:59:02]i000: Setting numeric variable 'PostgresqlInstalled_x64' to value 0
```

Comment: Can't vote up, but this worked. I've misunderstood the fragment part. @StephenJennings